# Torrent:  количество сидеров

Tags: torrent

Если на сайте есть торенты, как он выводит количество сидеров?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- раздавать самому. Следовательно, всю статистику знаем. Для множества файлов сложно.
- в параметрах торрент файла есть адрес, куда "стучать". Собрать статистику не вопрос.
- врать. Так многие фейковые сайты делают.

Comment: > раздавать самому. Следовательно, всю статистику знаем. Для множества файлов сложно.

На таких сайтах используют свой трекер, и они за данные такого рода отвечают.

Comment: Собственно второй способ и описывает работу классического треккера.

Comment: [KoVadim](http://hashcode.ru/users/2739/kovadim), врать не хорошо,  задумка: свой контент.

Comment: Да понятно, что врать - это плохо. Попробуйте поискать любой популярный контент - найдете тонны сайтов-клонов, которые его предлагают скачать торрентом, рисуют сотни сидеров, а по факту - там ничего нет.

Answer (score 0):

Сайты используют свой трекер, и в БД хранят всю информацию, которая обновляется в зависимости от возможностей сервера (периодически или по запросу с проверкой последнего запроса, если он свежий ( меньше часа, меньше  другого периода), то выдаются результаты предыдущего запроса. При хранении файлов на собственном сервере, есть возможность создать сида ( раздатчика).